# PHP, unexpected results when adding new entries to Array

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm writing code that allows me to collect images gathered by Instaloader python library, and put them into a gallery on my website. I have managed to collect and display these with no problem, however I have now moved to implement the caption for each post and I am running into problems with it.

The way the library downloads photos, if there is more than one photo in the collection it will suffix the post with _1, _2 etc based on the position of the image in the collection, with .txt files present for the caption.

example folder contents for a collection:

```
2022-12-26_14-14-01_UTC.txt
2022-12-26_14-14-01_UTC_1.jpg
2022-12-26_14-14-01_UTC_2.jpg
2022-12-26_14-14-01_UTC_3.jpg
```

The posts with single posts work fine
example:

```
2022-12-31_18-13-43_UTC.txt
2022-12-31_18-13-43_UTC.jpg
```

Main block of code:

```
$array = []; 
$account_name = "everton";
$file_directory = "images/instagram";
$count = 0;

$hasvideo = 0;
$hasCaption = 0;

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__DIR__)).'/'.$file_directory.'/');
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    $date = substr($file, 0, strpos($file, "_UTC"));
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Using strtolower to overcome case sensitive
    if($ext === 'jpg'){
        $count++;

        $collectionSize = (int)str_replace("_", "", str_replace(".jpg", "", explode("UTC",$file)[1]));
        if(!is_numeric($collectionSize)){
            $collectionSize = 0;
        }

        $arrayKey = array_search($date, array_column($array, 'date'));

        if($arrayKey){
            $amount = intval($array[$arrayKey]['collection-size']);
            
            if($collectionSize > $amount){
                $array[$arrayKey]['collection-size'] = (int)$collectionSize;
            }
        }else{
            array_push($array, array ("date" => $date, "collection-size" => (int)$collectionSize, "has-video" => false));
        }
    }
    
    if ($ext === "txt"){
        $file_location = dirname(realpath(__DIR__)).'/'.$file_directory.'/'. $file;
        $myfile = fopen( $file_location, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $caption = fread( $myfile, filesize($file_location));
        $arrayKey = array_search($date, array_column($array, 'date'));

        //$arrayKey returns false when there is a collection. 
        if($array[$arrayKey]){
            $array[$arrayKey]['caption'] = $caption;
        }else{
            array_push($array, array ("date" => $date, "caption" => $caption));
        }
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

$arrayKey is returning false when there is a collection over a regular single post.

I believe it is something todo with the file order in which these are read by the script since I'm assuming it will read (date).txt before it reads (date)_(collectionposition).jpg

if the array entry has already been created, the caption is added to the array data normally, if not (such as when there is a _1, _2 etc) then the array doesn't update with anything and throws no errors.

edit:
Further troubleshooting suggesting to me that the way im updating/checking for array keys based on the 'date' value is wrong, looking to find the correct way to handle these operations

Any guidance on what I can fix to make this work as intended is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let's study your code first.** The issue you mention, ie. the following line:

```
$arrayKey = array_search($date, array_column($array, 'date'));
```

...returns `false`, because the `$array` entry with the date hasn't been created when the `.txt` file is processed. (Your logic for creating the array member with `array_push` is further down the code.)

Simple fix to move onward to the relevant part of the `if/else` logic *when not yet defined*:

```
if($arrayKey !== false && $array[$arrayKey]){
...
```

In other words, if `$arrayKey` is not `false`, continue to add the value to the existing array member. Otherwise, create the array member.

Also, there's an issue where you process images, a warning generated at the first incidence:

```
$amount = intval($array[$arrayKey]['collection-size']);
```

This will fail with *Undefined array key "collection-size"*,  because the `collection-size` key doesn't exist yet. Fix e.g. with setting "default zero" using the null-coalescing operator before you try to operate on the array key:

```
$array[$arrayKey]['collection-size'] ??= 0;
```

These notes fix the errors, however it would be a good idea to separate the "entry creation" at the first instance of *either txt or jpg* -- with an empty array member with the intended keys, before any of your txt/jpg specific logic is executed. I would simply use the `$date` itself as the grouping, and with that you can also get rid of the `array_search`. For example, after extracting the date, with:

```
$array[$date] ??= [
    'date' => $date,
    'caption' => '',
    'collection-size' => 0,
    'has-video' => false,
];
```

And then modify the rest of your code to match. *Your code shouldn't depend on the order in which the files are read.* That order isn't guaranteed. Otherwise, you could always read the list of files into a regular array first, and then sort them, and iterate again while applying specific logic.

### Streamlined Code

The actual amount of code needed is much less than what you have. Here I've trimmed it down for you. I don't have your files, so here's some dummy data:

```
$files = <<<CWS
2022-12-26_14-14-01_UTC.txt
2022-12-26_14-14-01_UTC_1.jpg
2022-12-26_14-14-01_UTC_2.jpg
2022-12-26_14-14-01_UTC_3.jpg
2022-12-27_14-14-01_UTC.txt
2022-12-27_14-14-01_UTC_1.jpg
2022-12-27_14-14-01_UTC_2.jpg
2022-12-31_18-13-43_UTC.txt
2022-12-31_18-13-43_UTC.jpg
CWS;

$files = preg_split('~\v+~', $files);
```

You could also just `glob` the files into an array (= list of filepaths):

```
$file_directory = "images/instagram";
$files = glob(dirname(realpath(__DIR__)).'/'.$file_directory.'/*');
```

And then iterate as follows:

```
foreach($files as $filepath) {
    $filename = basename($filepath);
    $date = strstr($filename, '_UTC', true);
    
    $array[$date] ??= [
        'date' => $date,
        'caption' => '',
        'collection-size' => 0,
        'has-video' => false,
    ];
    
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
    if($ext === 'jpg'){
        // Each JPG increments collection size:
        $array[$date]['collection-size']++;
    }
    
    elseif ($ext === "txt"){
        // We use a dummy here:
        $caption = '---';
        // $caption = file_get_contents($filepath);

        $array[$date]['caption'] = $caption;
    }
}
```

Notice how much it shrank. What happened?

- We use `$date` as the grouping index for the array. No more `array_search`!
- We initialize a default entry for each date. No need for further checks or conditions!
- We ignore the `_3` etc. "collection size" in the filename: just increment +1 for each JPG.
- We use `glob` and `file_get_contents` instead of `readdir` and `fopen`.
- Order of files doesn't matter. (Feel free to test and `shuffle($files)`!)

Result:

```
array(3) {
    ["2022-12-26_14-14-01"] · array(4) {
        ["date"] · string(19) "2022-12-26_14-14-01"
        ["caption"] · string(3) "---"
        ["collection-size"] · int(3)
        ["has-video"] · bool(false)
    }
    ["2022-12-27_14-14-01"] · array(4) {
        ["date"] · string(19) "2022-12-27_14-14-01"
        ["caption"] · string(3) "---"
        ["collection-size"] · int(2)
        ["has-video"] · bool(false)
    }
    ["2022-12-31_18-13-43"] · array(4) {
        ["date"] · string(19) "2022-12-31_18-13-43"
        ["caption"] · string(3) "---"
        ["collection-size"] · int(1)
        ["has-video"] · bool(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @mickmackusa, I've updated the `strstr` and added `elseif` to the code. `switch` is the option I'd use myself, `match` is great but limited where multiple lines of code may be needed. The split is there just to provide the dummy data; OP will be using the directory listing array. If that were the source format, then `preg_match_all` would be the better way to go in reducing function calls from the loop.

Comment: In other notes, while OP's `opendir` / `readdir` also works, I've changed the directory reading to [`glob`](https://www.php.net/glob) to 1. help the code work with dummy data, and 2. to give the option to only read particular filetypes: `glob("*.{txt,jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);` for example. (Note though that this is case-sensitive.)

Comment: I very much appreciate your help on this, and the detail in which you've gone into explaining the more appropriate method! Thanks a lot.